# Help with creating a live USB with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: live-usb, gpt, mbr, startup-disk-creator, gnome-disk-utility

I'm trying to create a live USB with the latest Ubuntu but without success.

Steps I did:

1. Downloaded the ISO image
2. Verified the image
3. I tried with gnome disks, ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator and Etcher.

I tried all these apps both with MBR and GPT (6 tries in total) but nothing worked!

Then I tried with RUFUS from a windows PC and it was the only that worked.

btw Fedora 33 and ubuntu 20.04 both work with all these apps, so ubuntu 20.10 has probably changed something.

My laptop uses UEFI with secure boot disabled.

Comment: Hello @Avant, can you please explain what the problem "exactly" is?   I think we would be able to help better if we knew that :)   //Best wishes

Comment: Hey @WilliamMartens, thnx for the quick reply.

It just doesn't boot from USB, it boots from hard drive.

Comment: Oh,  okay - thanks for  answering, I had the similar problem before, I will come back and see if I can see what fixed it in my case, Have a continuing nice week anyway!

Comment: I think this is related:

* https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294335/ubuntu-20-10-iso-changes-uefi-based-booting

* https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-to-use-grub2-for-booting-installer-media-in-any-modes-on-all-architectures/16871

Comment: Oh yes, I have looked trough my pc but don't find the "solution" or (the notes - to use a more proper term),  I'm really not sure what causing it, I had it before as said :/

Comment: Have you tried the USB on a different computer?

Comment: No, I don't have other PC at the moment.